# Ajax datatables multiple column search

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable

I'm new to js and datables and I'm having a difficulty making single column search into multiple column search. Here's my code:

```
        var dataTable = $('#product_data').DataTable({
         "processing":true,
         "serverSide":true,
         "order":[],
         "ajax":{
            url:"fetch.php",
            type:"POST",
         },
         "columnDefs":[
            {
             "targets":[0,5,7],
             "orderable":false,
            },
         ],
        });

         function load_data(is_suppliers)
         {
          var dataTable = $('#product_data').DataTable({
           "processing":true,
           "serverSide":true,
           "order":[],
           "ajax":{
            url:"fetch.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{is_suppliers:is_suppliers}
           },
           "columnDefs":[
            {
             "targets":[0,5,7],
             "orderable":false,
            },
           ],
          });
         }

         $(document).on('change', '#supplier_filter', function(){
          var supplier = $(this).val();
          $('#product_data').DataTable().destroy();
          if(supplier != '')
          {
           load_data(supplier);
          }
          else
          {
           load_data();
          }
         });
```

And the query i used was:

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM products
INNER JOIN suppliers
ON suppliers.supplierid = products.supplier
";
$query .= " WHERE ";
if(isset($_POST["is_suppliers"]))
{
 $query .= "products.supplier = '".$_POST["is_suppliers"]."' AND ";
}

if(isset($_POST['search']['value']))
{
 $query .= '
 (productname LIKE "%'.$_POST['search']['value'].'%"
 OR category LIKE "%'.$_POST['search']['value'].'%")
 ';
}

if(isset($_POST['order']))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY productid DESC ';
}

$query1 = '';

if($_POST['length'] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}
```

(Edited- added full query except execute and fetch part)I've tried replicating the functions and replacing the values with the column i want and i also added another if(isset) to the query but only one column search will work and the others will show no matching records.

Comment: change the `AND` to an `OR`. As written your query will only find records where *all* columns searched have a match, not just any one of them.

Comment: also if thats your complete code your query has a hanging AND

Comment: I have already tried switching AND to OR  but still gives the same result of only one column being able to search.

Comment: @chiliNUT ive edited the post adding the full query except the execute and fetch part to keep it short.